# SQLite Studio auto increment is not working

Tags: sqlite

This is how my sql is:

```
CREATE TABLE character ( 
id   INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                    NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR( 15 )  NOT NULL 
);
```

However , while adding data to the table, id field is not auto incemented:

[image]

Do you know why is that?

Comment: A primary key cannot be NULL. That database does not have this table definition.

Comment: I copied and pasted your sql into sqlite manager plugin in Firefox and it works fine. Check structure of your table if it was created exactly with this command or try sqlite manager in Firefox and check if the reason is not browse application you are using.

Comment: yes it is also working for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything is fine. **You need to commit those 2 rows** into table and the AUTOINCREMENT values will be respected.

SQLiteStudio marks data "yet to be commited" using blue outline, just like on your screenshot. To commit data use "commit" button on toolbar (5th button from the left), or use keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+Enter".

Remember, as long as any data in SQLiteStudio is outlined with blue frame, the data is not yet in the database. If you close SQLiteStudio without commiting the data, you will lose your data.